# Angular version: 14.2.9 - "Form Data Binding Issue: Data Not Binding/Populating Properly - Help Needed"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-forms

I'm currently working with Angular version 14.2.9, using component library i am using is

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

and I'm encountering an issue when binding data to a form. I would like to implement a feature where, upon clicking an 'update' icon, a modal opens with the data pre-populated. After the user makes updates, the form's data should automatically clear. While I'm able to successfully log the data in the console, it doesn't appear to bind correctly to the respective text fields in my form. I've confirmed that the data reaches the console as expected. I've thoroughly reviewed my code and form setup, but I'm unable to determine why the data isn't displaying in the form fields as it should.

--> I want to populate form data on both icons (EDIT and VIEW)
but the criteria for both icons is different.

For VIEW modal:-
It simply binds data to a form when user click on View icon, a modal will appear with binding values.

For EDIT modal:-
When user click on edit icon it will open the modal with populating data and then after closing all values eq to null.

```
    clearData(){
    this.staffUserData = null;
}
```

I tried this to display data on console.log

```
console.log("Event Type:", eventData.eventType);
console.log("Selected Data:", eventData.data);
```

this is used to open modal on update-icon

**staff-button.component.ts**

```
 @Input() userData: staffUserData;
    constructor(protected modalService: NgbModal) {}
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if(this.userData != null && this.userData !=undefined){      
            const modalRef=this.modalService.open(CreateStaffFormComponent, {
              size: 'lg',
              backdrop: 'static',
            });
            modalRef.componentInstance.userData = this.userData;
            this.modalClosed.emit();
          }
    }
```

**list-staff.component.ts** :-

```
 handleIconClickEvent(eventData: { eventType: string, data: any }) {
    console.log("Event Type:", eventData.eventType);
    console.log("Selected Data:", eventData.data); 
    if(eventData.eventType === 'DELETE'){
      this.staffService.deleteData(eventData.data.id);
    }
    if(eventData.eventType === 'EDIT'){
      this.staffUserData = eventData.data;
    
    }
    if(eventData.eventType === 'VIEW'){
      const modalRef=this.modalService.open(ViewPopupComponent, {
        size: 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static',
      });
      modalRef.componentInstance.data = this.data;
      this.modalClosed.emit();
    }
  }
```

But here data is not populating/binding in edit and view icon..

**list-staff.component.html** :-

```
  <app-create-staff-button  [userData]="staffUserData" (modalClosed)="clearData()"></app-create-staff-button>
```

**staff-form.component.ts** :-

```
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
   if (this.userData) {
      this.createStaffForm.patchValue({
        firstName: this.userData.firstName || '', 
        lastName: this.userData.lastName || '',   
        userName: this.userData.userName || '',
  });
    }
  }
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this data binding issue within my Angular application.

I tried this for populating the data..

```
if (this.userData) {       
this.createStaffForm.patchValue({ firstName: this.userData.firstName || '',          
lastName: this.userData.lastName || '',   
userName: this.userData.userName || '',   
});     
}
```

view component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit,} from '@angular/core';
  import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
  import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    export class ViewPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  createStaffForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() data: any[];
  staffData: any;
  modalRef: any;
 

  constructor(protected modalService: NgbModal,
    protected activeModal: NgbActiveModal,

    ) { }
    openModal() {
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ViewPopupComponent);
    }
    

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("View Data:", this.data); 
   
  }
  close(){
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }
  }
```

view.component.html

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-12"> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5>View Staff Data</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">First Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-cy="firstName" data-cy= "firstName"id ="firstName" formControlName="firstName"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"  data-cy="lastName"  formControlName="lastName">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3 pt-0" data-cy="gender" >Gender</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <div class="radio radio-primary ms-2">
                        <input id="gender_male" type="radio" name="gender"  data-cy="male" value="0"
                        formControlName="gender">
                        <label for="gender_male" class="m-b-10">Male</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio radio-primary ms-2">
                        <input id="gender_female" type="radio" name="gender" data-cy="female"  value="1"
                        formControlName="gender">
                        <label for="gender_female" class="m-b-10">Female</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio radio-primary ms-2">
                        <input id="gender_other" type="radio" name="gender" data-cy="other"  value="2" checked=""
                        formControlName="gender">
                        <label for="gender_other" class="m-b-10">Other</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3 pt-0" data-cy="staff_type" >Staff Member Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <div class="radio radio-primary ms-2">
                        <input id="staff_type_fi" type="radio" name="staff_type" data-cy="finance_manager" value="0"
                        formControlName="staffType">
                        <label for="staff_type_fi" class="m-b-10">Finance Manager</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio radio-primary ms-2">
                        <input id="staff_type_su" type="radio" name="staff_type"  data-cy="support_manager"  value="1"
                        formControlName="staffType">
                        <label for="staff_type_su" class="m-b-10">Support Manager</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-cy="userName" formControlName="userName">
                  </div>
                </div> 

               <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" data-cy="password" formControlName="password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary me-1" btn-id="submit"  (click)="close()">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I added any default value, it displays a fixed value, but the data doesn't populate/bind.

**What I Expected to Happen:**
I expected that the data I logged in the console would populate the corresponding text fields in the form. This means that when I log data in the console, it should also display within the form fields.

**What Actually Resulted:**
However, despite verifying the data in the console, the data didn't populate the form fields as expected. The form fields remained empty, and the data binding didn't work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer it, eventhough your code is incomplete and you have not even mentioned which component library you are using (ng-zorro, Angular Material, ...?). Assuming you are using Angular Material: You haven't inserted the data correctly. You have to pass the data when you call modalService.open as part of the options object. This can be found in the Angular Material Docs:
[https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component]

So, in your case this should work:

```
const modalRef=this.modalService.open(ViewPopupComponent, {
  size: 'lg',
  backdrop: 'static',
  data: this.data
});
```

Inside of your popup component you can inject the data like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: unknown) { }
```

(replace type 'unknown' by a type definition that fits for you)

Remarks:

- Next time, please post all code which can be relevant for answering your question.
- Please also mention everything you use in addition to the framework.

Just some general tipps:

- Don't use 'any'. By using 'any' you loose the TypeScript benefits. By using 'any' you basically say that you don't care about type savety.
- You should use === instead of ==